# Binding multi-source data to GUI in Java

Tags: java, database, swing, csv

Thanks for taking time to read my question.

Here's my issue : I have different data files (.csv) that I need to basically cram into the same GUI. But there are some operations that I need to do on them, nothing really fancy though. And I figured those operations would really facilitated by the possibility of using the "Sort By" and "Group By". That's why I thought to import the .csv files as databases (they are actually databases exported into csv format).

So let's use a simple example : I used the SUM operation on a column, in addition to the Group By. And I want to display the result in, say, a JTable (or other), how should I proceed ? Keeping in mind that this operation must be done for each file, and I need to display the result from the others files in the same component.

Comment: Have you written some code yet that you can share?

Comment: Whats the issue with adding the data one after each other (reading from each csv file and adding to the table)? If you need to sort it, you can add data from the files to an arraylist and use the Collections.sort method, then display it in the JTable.

Comment: I want to display the results from all the files at the same time for the user. I don't want to use Arraylists because there some operations (like the sum of an entire column) would be too tedious.

Comment: http://java-sl.com/envelope.html could be useful

Comment: Where is the problem? Read first file, add data TableModel, read second file, add data to TableModel, read third file, add data to TableModel...